# Enter and store a number starting with 0 (zero) in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x, zero, octal

I am working on a simple student attendance program in Python2.  I am using an HID scanner that acts as a keyboard.  The student IDs each have a barcode with their ID numbers on them.  Unfortunately, the ID numbers start with zero, so that scanner produces the value with the zero.  Once the scan occurs, it produces the invalid token error since Python thinks it is an octal number and some of the numbers in the sequence are 8 and 9.

The simple code I am testing now is:

```
def Main():
    while(loop == True):
        scan = input('Please scan your ID: ')
        dateTime = time.strftime('%I:%M:%S   %d/%m/%y')
        print(dateTime)
        print(scan)
```

EDITED: The error is:

```
============== RESTART: /home/pi/Desktop/Barcode Entry Node2.py ==============
Please scan your ID: 0971558

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Barcode Entry Node2.py", line 18, in <module>
    Main()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Barcode Entry Node2.py", line 13, in Main
    scan = input('Please scan your ID: ')
  File "<string>", line 1
    0971558
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>>
```

I have tried a bunch of different work arounds, but they all give me an error.  I tried to convert it to a string in the declaration line but that did not seem to work the way I tried.  Also, the scanner does not have the option to enclose the input in quotation marks.  Anyone have the magic bullet I am missing? TIA

EDIT: sorry - wrong cut and paste . . . DUH!

Comment: can you provide some sample inputs?

Comment: Is this python 2? If so, use `raw_input()`, not `input()`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where the conversion actually fails? There is code actually relevant to your problem here.

Comment: The error confirms that the code you are running is not the code you chose to show us.

Comment: I messed up . . . the error text is correct now.

Comment: @davbow. Thanks for responding so quickly.

Answer (score 3):

using python 2, `input` interprets everything you enter (and it's also a security breach)

Since numbers starting with 0 are considered as octal in python 2 (no longer true in python 3 where you have to use the `0o` prefix), there's a syntax error because `0971558` contains digits higher than 7.

I'd use `raw_input` to get a real string:

```
scan = raw_input('Please scan your ID: ')
```

if you want to convert as integer, `int` accepts leading zeroes all right so `int(scan)` will work without stripping them off.

note that your original code works all right in python 3.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Fabre - let me do that . . . my students were trying to decide between 2 and 3 . . . and went with 2 because they thought it would be easier to connect to MYSQL based on their research.  I will push them towards 3. Again, thank you

Comment: @dvbow. There is very little that remains easier in 2 these days.

Comment: 2020 will mark the end of the support for python 2. I've migrated a rather big workshop from 2 to 3 without major issues (except for some missing bindings so we had some small rewrites)